# How to force browsers to accepte all further SSL certificates

Tags: tls, certificates, chrome, firefox, internet-explorer

I am using the last versions of IE, Firefox and Google Chrome web browsers on Windows 8. How can force these browsers to accept automatically the SSL certificates of any website I will visit ?
I know this is not a good security practice, but I do it for a specific security reason, indeed (virtualization and some stuff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are designed specifically to not allow this. As you brought up yourself, that would be a massive security risk.

If you want to be able to browse your own systems without clicking "confirm security exception" a million times, add the certificates to your trust store on your computer, using the "Certificates" MMC snap-in.

This can be done even better if you create your own CA, generate the certificates for your systems from that CA, then install that CA's certificate as trusted.

If you're in a domain environment, you can even create group policies to deploy the trusted certificate settings to as many computers as you want, automatically.

This way you trust your own resources without buying certificates, and don't break your internet security.